# Can someone explain why 19.99 * 100 is 1998 in ruby?

Tags: floating-point

Using ruby version 2.0.0p247 or 1.9.3p286

In irb console

```
9.99  * 100 = 999.0
```

and

```
29.99 * 100 = 2999.0
```

but

```
19.99 * 100 = 1998.9999999999998
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here? I get that it could be a bug in ruby core but surely the logic is the same for the above 3 calculations?

Comment: Because floating point math (in any language, not just Ruby).

Comment: does ruby works with datatypes, if so what is the datatype of the values?

Comment: Ruby supports rational arithmetic, but you have to ask for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Directly from the ruby [Float documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Float.html):

> Float objects represent inexact real numbers using the native
>   architecture's double-precision floating point representation.
>
> Floating point has a different arithmetic and is an inexact number. So
>   you should know its esoteric system. see following:
>
> http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html
>   https://github.com/rdp/ruby_tutorials_core/wiki/ruby-talk-faq#floats_imprecise
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Example from the Ruby Tutorials Core

```
Example of odd behavior:

>> (2.0-1.1) == 0.9
=> false
```

Answer (score 5):

In order to correctly calculate, make sure that you use the BigDecimal data type, particularly important for financial stuff.

```
19.99.to_d * 100.0.to_d
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer this specific question:

> but surely the logic is the same for the above 3 calculations?

It is. But the stored value is not a directly copy of the decimal representation that you input as a `Float` literal in the console. Instead it is converted to an internal form. To understand what is going on, you need to see the internal *binary* representation used to store the values that you are manipulating. Then you will see it is 100% consistent, but not 100% precise.

Answer (score 0):

The result of multiplication of the [`Float`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Float.html)ing point number to `Integer`

```
19.99 * 100
```

is really:

```
# => 1998.9999999999998
```

Because of usage the 64-bit *double-precision* floating point to store the number, it is [known issue of accuracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems). However you can get the normalized float:

```
puts "%.1f" % (19.99 * 100)
# => 1999.0
```